# Fix range of ticks in ggplot?(broaden the plot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

The dataset has this structure:

```
    how_many  prod_vers   when
1        14          v1 2016-01
2       654          v2 2016-01
3         8          v1 2016-02
4       373          v2 2016-02
5        33          v1 2015-03
6       240          v2 2016-03
```

there is this plot:

```
az$dt <- as.character(az$dt)
ggplot(az, aes(x = dt, y = nu)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(app_version ~ .) +
  xlab("Month") +
  ylab("Count") +
  ggtitle("Count by Month & App Version")

ggplot(az, aes(x = dt, y = nu)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(app_version ~ substring(dt, 1, 4)) +
  xlab("Month") +
  ylab("Count") +
  ggtitle("Count by Month, Year & App Version")][2]][2]
```

i would like to know how to make the ticks include all the months. i tried this `scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 155, 5), lim = c(0, 155))` but doesn't do that.

The plot:
[image]Here is the dataset:[link](http://%20mediafire.com/file/tt2l50nz4dzgaw6/DataforSover.csv)

Comment: It does..? All months have a tick  and (illegible) label?

Comment: i want to make it look proper. I want to know how to widen the plot and how to change the ticks in general

Comment: The x axis labels will have to be rotated 90 deg. Better idea would be to flip x and y axis. That way the month labels are horizontal. In fact just adding `coord_flip()` to your existing code should make it usable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually need to change the y-axis. Just fix your data. For example

```
#Load package & data
library(ggplot2)
az = readr::read_csv("DataforSover.csv")
colnames(az)[2] = "nu"
```

First we subset `dt` to extract the year and month

```
az$year = substr(az$dt, 1, 4)
az$month = substr(az$dt, 6,7)
```

Then just plot as before

```
g = ggplot(az, aes(x = month, y = nu)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(app_version ~ year) + 
  xlab("Month") +
  ylab("Count") +
  ggtitle("Count by Month, Year & App Version")
```

To get

[image]

If you did want to tweak the x-axis, then just change the labels, e.g.

```
labels = rep("", 12)
labels[c(1, 6, 12)] = c("Jan", "Jun", "Dec")
g + scale_x_discrete(labels = labels)
```

[image]